# how to make variable accessible in requirejs callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, requirejs

I have a piece of code with requirejs

```js
var path = this.formatPath(path);
require([path], function (template) {

//....code here

});
```

And I'd like to print the path inside the requirejs callback function.

Something like this

```js
var path = this.formatPath(path);
require([path], function (template) {

//console.log(path)

});
```

However because the callback function is in a different scope, I can't access it.

How do I pass the path variable in the callback function?

Comment: In the examples shown your function body does have access to `path` from the surrounding scope. Or is your code different from the two code blocks you're showing (and your callback function is declared in a different location)?

Comment: *"However because the callback function is in a different scope, I can't access it."* The callback function *isn't* in a different scope in your question, and the `console.log(path)` would work just fine.

Comment: These lines are in sequence in my code as you see them however adding console.log(path) inside the callback function yields `undefined`

Comment: Does `console.log(path)` directly after `var path = this.formatPath(path);` show the correct value (and not `undefined`)?

Comment: Yes it does that's why I'm confused :(

Comment: Are you reassigning `path` anywhere in your code? If the callback to the `require` runs asynchronously (which I'm guessing it does), then you might be reassigning it before your callback runs. You can try `const path = this.formatPath(path);` to ensure you're not accidentally re-assigning it anywhere (as making your variable const will throw if it is)

Comment: I see it's entirely possible that it gets reassigned because this is loading lots of templates. I'll try and investigate further to see if it's happening asynchronously